# getting google places api key

Tags: google-api-java-client

I have need to google places api, now i obthain the api key, i download the google-api-java-client, and i added this at my project (that use android sdk 2.3.3.) 
so, where is the problem, because I have copied an example for testing that  all procedure that i doing is good. 
Now, or the problem is the version of google-api-java that i downloaded, or the example is good for other android sdk version.
what i want to ask is: what version google-api-java-client i have to install for android sdk 2.3.3?
where is a good manual for google-api-java-client?
if the problem isn't one of that I said, who could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any `google-api-java-client`. If you are trying to get a list of cities then just use the api as follows to get the list of `possible cities` and `then use xml or json parsing` to use the result according to your need

xml

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=delh&sensor=true&key=your key here
```

json

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=delh&sensor=true&key=your key here
```

similariy you can get list of lots of other places like electronic stores or restaurant in a particular area. See this link here [autocomplete google places](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete), [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). Clear your intentions about what you want to implement and help will be provided